# how to prevent datepicker css from changing

Tags: css, datepicker, uidatepicker

I am trying to use `DatePicker` in my site. I have a *main.css* and it has a style as follows:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;     
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 75%;
}
```

When I put the datepicker into the site the style of datepicker is changing. 
Is there any way to prevent from changing it?

Comment: Please be more accurate: how do you apply datepicker? what exactly is changing?

Comment: The body class in main.css applies for all the page and that changes the css style of datepicker? How can I prevent it?

Comment: You have to work on the date picker css to accomplish the desired out put if body css is the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, find the specific style property(properties) in the body that affect your date picker and then specifically reset those properties in the datepicker css.

eg
/*main.css*/

body{
   font-size: 2px;

}

for example ,the font-size will apply to everything you put on the page (including the datepicker) so to fix it go to datepicker css, and change font-size property for the specific element.

ie

/*datepicker css */

#foo{

font-size: 4px;

}
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can't **prevent** it as such, but you can **override** it and put it back as it was. You'll need to apply CSS to the date picker itself to override what the body styles are doing to it.

Does the date picker element have an ID, so you can apply CSS directly to it?

Comment: my date picker is as follows:Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">                                                                    $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   yearRange:"-90:+0",
   showOn: "both",
   buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
   buttonImageOnly: true
  });
 });

Comment: So it's standard text box with some Javascript attached that does the actual date picker part. You need to know what HTML elements that Javascript creates before you can begin to work out what CSS you need.